# How to start my ubuntu 14.04 64 bit?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I bought lately an usb external hard drive Verbatim 1TB and I tried to install a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. I have also in my laptop an internal hdd 320GB with my Windows 7. All the installation process went well, I created 3 partitions on my external drive: ext4 and swap for Ubuntu and ntfs for the data. I put Ubuntu on the first one. The problem appears when I try to boot up the system. I can see GRUB menu with Ubuntu and Windows 7 listed on but none entry works. When I highlight any of them, hit Enter GRUB menu disappears, the screen gets violet and nothing happens. Doesn't matter if I choose Ubuntu or Windows 7 the system doesn't boot. What am I doing wrong? Help me, please. Kind regards. Marcin
PS. this is my grub.cfg file:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=pl_PL
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
}
submenu 'Opcje zaawansowane dla systemu Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, za pomocą systemu Linux 3.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
        fi
        echo    'Wczytywanie systemu Linux 3.13.0-32-generic...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Wczytywanie początkowego dysku RAM...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
        fi
        echo    'Wczytywanie systemu Linux 3.13.0-32-generic...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Wczytywanie początkowego dysku RAM...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4cfc555-23dc-4da2-91bc-eb6d05873e54
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (na /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-3E5F-3A2B' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  3E5F-3A2B
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3E5F-3A2B
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (na /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-30D09BEBD09BB616' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  30D09BEBD09BB616
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 30D09BEBD09BB616
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: edit the grub commands before launch, remove the quiet-boot option, report interesting things. Also post the /boot/grub/grub.cfg and the output of  `ls` at the grub command prompt

Comment: what make and model of laptop are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Trey :) When I try to edit GRUB while booting I don't find quiet boot option so I cannot remove it. And as a matter of fact I don't know how get the output of ls at the grub command prompt :/ My laptop it's ASUS K52JC

Comment: Thank you for your answer Wilf. My laptop it's ASUS K52JC

Comment: here's the output of ls at the grub command prompt: (hd0)(hd0,msdos3)(hd0,msdos2)(hd0,msdos1)(hd1)(hd1,msdos5)(hd1,msdos2)(hd1,msdos1)

Comment: Finally I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.2 64 bit, installed it and it works fine :) I don't know what was the issue with Ubuntu 14.04.1 64 bit. Nevertheless I thank you all for your efforts and help. Best regards. Marcin